# Adding an excel sheet to an html web page

Tags: html, excel

I have done a lot of research but still can not figure out a solution. I am trying to have a table appear from my excel sheet and appear in my html document. I know I can do this but can not figure out a way top have it where I can edit the sheet and it readjust on my page to show the new data. Just looking for a direction to look in.

Again, I want to have it so I can add to an excel sheet and a table appears in my html doc and will change when I change my sheet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For show data on your web pages you need a scripting language, this is not a simple table show, this is a part of database from excel.